# When to remind with "Remind me later"?

Tags: mobile, web, notification, time, push-notification

What are some things I should consider and think about that will help me figure out when we should remind the user of something?

For context: Our mobile app is basically a wine collecting app. When users tap to consume their bottle in the app, they can make a note about the wine which will be stored in the archive. We want to be able to give them the option to write the note at a later time, hence why we want to put in the "remind me later" button. I'm trying to think of when would be the best time to remind them (push notification) of this? After 3 hours? 6 hours?

Comment: What is the importance of writing a note that would necessitate a reminder? Will something critical happen to the wine if the user doesn't add a note?

Comment: @Izquierdo nope, nothing critical will happen if they dont add a note. Its just for them to remind them of lets say, the tasting notes, where they might've drank it, etc. The importance of it is for situations where lets say they are with friends, finished a wine bottle and want to record (consume) it, but don't want to put in a note at the moment because they want to enjoy being with their friends at the moment. They also have the choice to not make a note at all.

Comment: Thanks for the additional context. It's good that you're thinking of the user's experience in the moment. One more question - are these notes shareable? Can other users see them?

Answer (score 1):

Since wine is often consumed in the evening, it's probably best to wait at least until the next day to nudge the user to leave notes (otherwise you might remind them in the middle of the night after they've fallen asleep, or first thing in the morning when they don't want to be thinking about wine).

It sounds like the notes will help the user remember things about the wine in case they want to find it / buy it again, so you also don't want to wait too long, lest they start forgetting what they liked about it.

Push notifications often get turned off when they're not for important functions, such as sports scores or reminders to check into flights. Consider instead an in-app notification the next day (perhaps during the user's afternoon or evening) that could say something like, "How was La Crema Chardonnay? Write some notes." The notification could put a badge on the app's icon as a subtle reminder.

If there's an activity feed in the app, you could also put a nudge to leave comments there as well.